# Automatically strip spaces from username in django-registration

Tags: django, django-forms, validation, django-registration

My users aren't very smart. They occasionally try to register with usernames that begin or end with spaces and then get confused when registration fails. How can I automatically strip those spaces?

(overriding `clean_username` doesn't seem to work because the field is a RegexField, and I think validation throws an error almost at field instantiation time, when the given string doesn't conform to the regex).

Answer (score 0):

You would want to override the clean() method of the form itself, then run strip() on the username data, then call the super().clean().

You can see the order of events in the docs to help you understand when the regex validator would run. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation